# Android native library linker stops working after gradle update

Tags: android, c, gradle, cmake, linker

My project stops working after updating gradle.
I'm using a C library in Android though JNI.
Using Cmake to compile and join the libraries
Before, it compiled and linked without a problem, but now there is an error at link time when building the project.

It throw this error:

```
/home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/src/main/cpp/kotlin-jni.c:152: error: undefined reference to 'find_best_order'
```

This is an extended error message that android studio also gives after trying to build the project:

```
> Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug FAILED
Build multiple targets main_armeabi-v7a this_library_armeabi-v7a process_control_armeabi-v7a
ninja: Entering directory `/home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a'
[1/1] Linking C shared library /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libthis_library.so
FAILED: /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libthis_library.so 
: && /home/my_user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=/home/my_user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/my_user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libthis_library.so -o /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libthis_library.so CMakeFiles/this_library.dir/kotlin-jni.c.o  used_library/src/libmodule_used_library.a  /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libprocess_control.so  -latomic -lm && :
/home/my_user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: used_library/src/libmodule_used_library.a: member at 3324 is not an ELF object
/home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/src/main/cpp/kotlin-jni.c:152: error: undefined reference to 'find_best_order'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process ninja with arguments {-C /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a main this_library process_control}
  ninja: Entering directory `/home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a'
  [1/1] Linking C shared library /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libthis_library.so
  FAILED: /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libthis_library.so 
  : && /home/my_user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi19 --gcc-toolchain=/home/my_user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/my_user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libthis_library.so -o /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libthis_library.so CMakeFiles/this_library.dir/kotlin-jni.c.o  used_library/src/libmodule_used_library.a  /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libprocess_control.so  -latomic -lm && :
  /home/my_user/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: used_library/src/libmodule_used_library.a: member at 3324 is not an ELF object
  /home/my_user/Documents/Proyects/optandroid/app/src/main/cpp/kotlin-jni.c:152: error: undefined reference to 'find_best_order'
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is the CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Optandroid)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_subdirectory(used_library)

add_library(this_library
        SHARED
        kotlin-jni.c
        )

# Include libraries needed for kotlin-jni lib
target_link_libraries(this_library
            process_library
            android
            log)
```

`used_library` is the library directory, it builds the library `process_library`, and `this_library` it is what I use for JNI.

This is a pure C project, nothing of C++, so it is not the problem of C++ changing the names of functions.

I corroborated that the problem starts by updating gradle in the project by taking an older proyect which use this library in exactly the same way, and just making the update, it works before, but has the exactly same error after.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At the end the problem was the NDK version. I just updated NDK to the newest version and started worked like before.